# HttpServletRequest.getSession(false) returns null in webFilter

Tags: jsf-2, jboss, wildfly, servlet-filters, httpsession

i have a JSF application running on Wildfly 10, and using a webfilter **Filter.java** to check whether user is logged in(here showing the doFilter method):

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class Filter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
@Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    String requestURI = request.getRequestURI().replaceFirst(";.*", "");


    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session != null && session.getAttribute("user") != null) {
      // User already logged in ...continue
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
      return;
    }

    if ("partial/ajax".equals(request.getHeader("Faces-Request"))) {
      // If ajax request, return special XML response instructing JSF ajax to send a redirect.
      response.setContentType("text/xml");
      response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
      response.getWriter().printf(LoginCheckFilter.AJAX_REDIRECT_XML, loginURL);
    } else {
      // User not logged in.Forward to login page
      response.sendRedirect(loginURL);
    }
  }
```

Additionally i have a SessionScoped Bean **LoginBean.java**, to login a user. Each login creates a new session with getSession(true):

```
@Named("loginBean")
@SessionScoped
@URLBeanName("loginBean")
public class LoginBean extends BasePageBean {


  /**
   * Login user
   */
  public void login() {
    HttpSession session = getSession(true);
    try {
      // login and redirect to correct page ......
    } catch (Throwable t) {

      return;
    }
  }
```

everything is working fine. But when i have logged in on one browser tab and i try to login on a second browser tab, i have to click login button twice to be able to login. Debugging, i see that with the first attempt

```
 HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
```

in Filter.java returns Null and user is redirected to login page again, although loginBean has created a new Session with :

```
 HttpSession session = getSession(true);
```

Only when login button is clicked second time, the login succeeds. How can the session be null here although i am explicitly creating a new session in my loginBean for each login attempt. Is this some phishing protection? or does this have to do with the scope of the LoginBean? i am kind of stuck with this at the moment.

the **getSession** method looks like this:

```
public static HttpSession getSession(boolean newSession) {
    FacesContext facescontext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (facescontext == null)
      return null;
    ExternalContext contx = (ExternalContext) facescontext.getExternalContext();
    if (contx == null)
      return null;
    if (newSession) {
      contx.invalidateSession();
    }
    return (HttpSession) contx.getSession(true);
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: In a real sessionscoped bean (check the import, is it the right sessionscoped annotation?), there is no need to create the session mamually. It is done for you.

Comment: the import is :
 import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;

Still not understanding why the session is not null only the second time i click  login button? Is the filter trying to read the session before the sessionscoped bean creates the new session?

Comment: i am explicitly recreating session(invalidating old one) with every new login, because i do not want multi tab use of my application. Once logged in from a new tab , the old tab should have a stale session.

Comment: Debug the requests and responses. Maybe the second tab is unaware of the new session and sends the old sessionid cookie, resulting in a session not being found etc... The order in which things are called are important too. Tip: don't develop your own security framework but use an existing one. Regarding your last comment: What if the user does not open the login page in a new tab but another page. How do you prevent that? Rethink your architecture/requirements would be another suggestion.

Comment: Hi Kukeltjs, thanks for your comments. If you can write your last comment as an answer, i will accept it as an answer to my question. Thks